# Unable to boot system after "upgrade"

Tags: package-management

I've seen similar answers on here, but I think my situation may be a little different.

I recently attempted to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver using the Terminal, and I'm afraid I did something wrong in the process. Specifically, I was using this tutorial to guide me through: [How To Upgrade To Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver)

Anyhow, I started by doing a full upgrade:

> $ sudo apt update
>
> $ sudo apt upgrade
>
> $ sudo apt dist-upgrade

Then, I removed all old packages using:

> $ sudo apt autoremove

Then, I did:

> $ sudo apt install update-manager-core

And after that, I ran the upgrade utility:

> $ sudo do-release-upgrade

Unfortunately, I think I followed these instructions a bit too closely and tried to *force* the upgrade:

> $ sudo do-release-upgrade -d

I think this is what messed up my system - probably the new release isn't available yet. If that's the case, is there a way I can at least restore the old one? I don't care about the lost files. I just want my machine to be usable again!

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the output during boot up it could be many things. I had an issue with the most recent update to the kernel. I opened the GRUB menu on boot and chose the previous kernel. You can open that menu by either holding `SHIFT` or `ESC` during boot. Once in that menu go to Advanced to choose a different kernel. Post the output here and I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try. A friend of mine had suggested something similar.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this. What I had to do was a factory reset of my machine (it's a Dell XPS-13). I lost my data, but fortunately, there wasn't anything irreplaceable on it.

To do this, I had to enter the GNU GRUB bootloader menu and select "Restore Ubuntu 16.04 to factory state."

I'm still hoping that there is a way to do upgrades without losing data in the future, however!

It does seem that the system wasn't configured quite correctly to begin with, as I noticed that some packages won't update properly. Thanks for your advice!